# PHP classes: ArrayAccess interface - Is it possible to use the array interface directly in a class?

Tags: php, class, static-methods, static-members, arrayaccess

In PHP, I'm trying to access directly a class member (using the ArrayAccess interface) without having to create a new instance.

For example:

```
class my_class implements ArrayAccess {
    private static $d=array();
    function offsetGet($o){return self::$d[$o];}
    function offsetSet($o,$v){self::$d[$o]=$v;}
}
my_class['foo']='bar';//Syntax error
echo my_class['foo'];
```

All I want to know is if there is ANY way of making this happen without having to do `$var=new my_class();`

I don't want to do that unless it is EXTREMELY necessary and that there is no way around that syntax error.

I want to get rid of that syntax error, if possible.

I'm not 100% sure if it is possible (probably not), but better task than dying in doubt and never trying.

I'm using PHP 5.4.7 on Windows 8 Pro x64, running on a intel core2quad i586 2.63ghz (just in case).

Comment: And why can't you just use an array?

Comment: Because i want to do other tasks like running functions and adding getters and setters. Besides, I want to keep everything static, and not having instances that simply get or set values to the parent static class. Then i would have to create static and non-static members in the same class with the same name, which is not possible and is absurd.

Comment: "Then i would have to create static and non-static members in the same class with the same name". It is common practice to create a 'Package' based approach to this. Basically you have a class which can be instantiated and represents an object (either from store or otherwise), and then you have a class which has the ability to manipulate several objects. In doctrine these are known as Table classes, in Propel, peer classes. With this approach you can separate member variables by either attaching them to actual object, or 'Package' class.

Comment: I don't want that. i want to use the class as close as a variable and as an array. Like how you do `$foo['bar']`, i want to do `my_class['foo']`. Besides, i have a `setter` method, and I believe it is impossible to do `$class=new my_class(); $class->setter($param);` and `my_class::setter($param);`

Comment: Have you looked into magic getters/setters? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Comment: They have the limitations of having to create an instance, not providing an array-like access and when the property is set, they won't fire! And I want to set setters and getters only for specific and unknown properties.

Comment: Why not work with the static array directly? `my_class::$d['foo'] = 'bar';`

Comment: As I said, i want it to work as close as a variable and as an array, like how you do $foo['bar'], i want to do my_class['foo'].

Comment: I don't know why people are so fond of questioning the OP's intentions and not helping them understand what they want to do, even if it's pointless?
The short answer would've been: "No, interfaces are not static, they work on instantiated objects."

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see it is impossible, so, I really had to use new instances.

Here is the result:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_STRICT);//removes the "Strict Standards" warning, don't do this
final class session implements ArrayAccess {
    //session data
    private static $s=null;

    //function (setters and getters)
    private static $f=array('s'=>array(),'g'=>array());//general setter/getter
    private $c=array('s'=>array(),'g'=>array());//private setter/getter

    function setter($k,$f=null)
    {
        if(($a=func_num_args())<=1)return!$a?false:((@$this)?(@$this->c['s'][$k]):(@self::$f['s'][$k]));
        else if($f==null){if(@$this)unset($this->c['s'][$k]);else unset(self::$f['s'][$k]);return true;}
        else return is_callable($f)&&(@$this?$this->c['s'][$k]=$f:self::$f['s'][$k]=$f);
    }

    function getter($k,$f=null)
    {
        if(($a=func_num_args())<=1)return!$a?false:((@$this)?(@$this->c['g'][$k]):(@self::$f['g'][$k]));
        else if($f==null){if(@$this)unset($this->c['g'][$k]);else unset(self::$f['g'][$k]);return true;}
        else return is_callable($f)&&(@$this?$this->c['g'][$k]=$f:self::$f['g'][$k]=$f);
    }

    //==== arrayaccess ====
    //extra: setters and getters implemented when accessing $session['offset']
    //       setter: gives the value, expects a value in return
    //       getter: gives the value, returns the value returned by the getter
    function offsetSet($o,$v){@self::$s[$o]=(@$this->c['s'][$o])?$this->c['s'][$o]($v,$o):(@self::$f['s'][$o]?call_user_func(self::$f['s'][$o],$v,$o):@self::$s[$o]);}
    function offsetExists($o){return isset(self::$s[$o]);}
    function offsetUnset($o){unset(self::$s[$o]);}
    function offsetGet($o){return(@$this->c['g'][$o])?$this->c['g'][$o](@self::$s[$o]):(@self::$f['g'][$o]?call_user_func(self::$f['g'][$o],@self::$s[$o]):@self::$s[$o]);}
    //==== arrayaccess ====
}

$s=new session();

$s->setter('test',function($ob){return$ob>6?'bigger than 6':'lower than 6';});

session::setter('test',function($st){return$st<5?'lower than 5':'bigger than 5';});
session::setter('test',null);//*deletes the setter,*/ session::setter('test');//return setter

$s['test']=5;

var_dump($s->setter('test'),session::setter('test'),$s['test']);
//expected output (php 5.3.0): object(Closure)#2 (1) { ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$ob"]=> string(10) "" } } NULL string(12) "lower than 6"
```

I know it look awful, but works as intended!

All data is shares across all new instances and all the setters in the general context are executed as expected.

If you want to use this code for you, remember this:

- `session::[sg]etter('test',null);` is NOT the same as `session::[sg]etter('test');`!
- The setter has 2 parameter (value and offset), while the getter only has 1 (the value);
- Both the setter and getter MUST return a value!

In one of the comments I said this:

> I have a setter method, and I believe it is impossible to do $class=new my_class(); $class->setter($param); and my_class::setter($param);

Well, it is not impossible, it just isn't standard (that's why the 1st line is `error_reporting(E_ALL^E_STRICT);`). Without this line, PHP goes crazy when you try to do `session::setter('test');`.

Comment: There is a great quote from the first Jurassic Park: "You were so busy worrying about whether you could, you didn’t stop to think about whether you should." Just the fact that you have to relax strict standards to avoid php going crazy should be a red flag that this not the right approach. Not only is that code a train-wreck from a maintainability perspective, have you even profiled it? I'm curious if all those anonymous functions calls are faster, the same, or slower than making calls to concrete functions.

Comment: I'm not worried about being super-fast or anything. I simply want it simple to use, not simple to make and run. They are as optimized as they can be, in my honest opinion (except for the error suppressing (@) instructions everywhere, instead of using `isset()`). I have mentioned that the strict warning is when I access `session::[gs]etter()` instead of `session->[gs]etter()`.